# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement (Inserting Multiple Records From Gridview to Access)

Tags: database, ms-access, datagridview, save, multiple-records

I am trying to save all my data in a DataGridView into an Access database but I'm getting this error: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.` My code follows:

```
try
{
  string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\MotoFix.mdb;";

  OleDbCommand Com = new OleDbCommand();

  for (int i = 0; i < gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    using (OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
      string str;
      Con.Open();
      str = @"INSERT INTO Transaction(tranNo, custID, pID, userID, orderNo, sDate) VALUES ('" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Transaction Number"].Value + "', '" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Customer ID"].Value + "'," + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Referral ID"].Value + ",'" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Cashier ID"].Value + "','" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Order Number"].Value + "','" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells["Date"].Value + "');";
      using (Com = new OleDbCommand(str, Con))
      {
        Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `TRANSACTION` is a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) in Access SQL. Try `INSERT INTO [Transaction] ...`.

Comment: I already changed it but I encountered this error No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sDate is a date type you may need to format it - Format("YYYY-mm-DD",sDate) or Format("YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:ss",sDate)

Comment: Somthing like:  str = "INSERT INTO Transaction(tranNo, custID, pID, userID, orderNo, sDate) VALUES ('" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Transaction Number").Value + "', '" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Customer ID").Value + "'," + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Referral ID").Value + ",'" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Cashier ID").Value + "','" + gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Order Number").Value + "','" + Strings.Format(gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Date").Value, "YYYY-mm-DD") + "');";

Comment: I encountered No value given for one or more required parameters. :(

Comment: Its telling you that you are missing a value for one of your 6 parameters.  Check your quotes and comer's and ensure everything is correct.  
Consider breaking it out so its easyer to read. assigning short variables for each value item 
  ie make a variable TransNo and set it to gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows(I).Cells("Transaction Number").Value
Then use the TransNo variable to build the sql